# R is a ring which has no nonzero nilpotent element. Deduce that all idempotents of R belongs to center.

Tags: abstract-algebra

And the question has a hint:
If $a^2=a$, then $(ara-ar) ^2=(ara-ra)^2=0$ for all r.

Comment: With the hint you got, there is absolutely nothing to do but confirm what it says, and you're done. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^2=a$, then $(ara-ar) ^2 =ara^2ra-ara^2r-arara+arar=arara-arar-arara+arar=0$

In the same way we get $(ara-ra)^2=0.$

Since in $R$ each nilpotent element $=0$, we get

$ara=ar $ and $ara =ra.$

Hence

$$ra=ara=ar$$

for all $r \in R.$